How to enable pinch zoom on mobile after requestFullscreen?
I'm trying to use requestFullscreen() functionality of Javascript and it looks like it disables pinch zoom when on mobile. Is there a way to enable it, I've looked for it but I did't found any solution.
Here's an example.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=12.0, minimum-scale=.25, user-scalable=yes"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container" style="background-color: white;">
        <button onclick="fullscreen()">Click here</button>
        <p id="message">Example</p>
    </div>

    <script>
        function fullscreen() {
            document.getElementById('container').requestFullscreen();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>

